# How to add two arrays using openMP?

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, openmp, addition

I am trying to parallelize this:  c[i]=a[i]+b[i] 
By using C program I am getting:

```
Elapsed time = 1667417 nanoseconds
```

with OpenMP I get:

```
Elapsed time = 8673966 nanoseconds
```

I don't clearly understand why this is happening and what needs to be done to parallelize this code. I am assuming that it is very simple addition so probably parallelism is not getting exploited here but would like to know the correct reason and any other way by which I could effectively parallelize this addition. I also tried using dynamic, guided and various chunksizes but it gives more or less similar results.

```
#define N 100
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i;
        float a[N], b[N], c[N];
        uint64_t diff; /* Elapsed time */
        struct timespec start, end;

    /* Some initializations */
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,10) num_threads(4) 
        for (i=0; i < N; i++){
            a[i] = b[i] = i * 1.0;
        }
        /*add two arrays*/
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start); /* mark start time */
        #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(4) 
        for (i=0; i<N; i++){
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
            printf("Thread number:%d,c[%d]= %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(),i,c[i]);

        }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end); /* mark the end time */

        diff = BILLION * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;


printf("\nElapsed time = %llu nanoseconds\n", (long long unsigned int) diff);
    }
```

Comment: 100 integer elements is small enough that the time taken to start the threads is likely to be much higher than the time saved by using multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be true but I also tried adding more elements and still the elapsed time is more by using openmp as compared to the normally compiled code without openmp. I think this is because the elements initialized in the array are incremented by 1 everytime and so the elements towards the end of the array take more time to compute? Is there something with the compute to communicate ratio.

Comment: Note that `schedule(static,10)` with `float` elements may cause a lot of _cache contention_. It involves 40 bytes, while typical cache line size is 64 bytes.

Comment: Also, you cannot reason about performance if you print from multiple threads. Do not use I/O within loop. That's likely the reason for very high time; looping over 100 elements should be much much faster than 1,7 [ms]. I tried that in Wandbox and without OpenMP and **without prints** the program reported 1200 [ns], i.e., more than 1000x less than yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No speed-up with useless printf's using OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711456/no-speed-up-with-useless-printfs-using-openmp)

Comment: In addition to the other comments, it makes little sense to shut off simd vectorization for the parallel test, regardless of whether you used it for the serial comparison.  That's another "possible duplicate," maybe not as easy to find.  The length of 100 barely approaches what is needed to get most of the benefit of simd with 1 thread, so additional threads will be counter-productive.  (static,10) would be a bad choice if you did decide to vectorize.